# Execute complex Titan queries through java

Tags: java, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am trying to find a good way to get Edges and vertices by various properties through java.

Is this only possible through installing Gremlin and Gremlin for java or REST.
Or by getting all the edges and iterating through them (quite costly).

Answer (score 1):

There are examples in the [Titan documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/gremlin.html). The `has()` step is a basic way of filtering vertices or edges by property. There are many more examples in the [Apache TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#has-step) (the core graph API that Titan implements).

Comment: But I'll have to use the gremlin java thing?

Comment: Yes. Gremlin is written in Java. Full javadoc is here http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/

Comment: If you want to set up a server to use HTTP API, you can find more directions in the TinkerPop docs.

Comment: Does it make any performance difference using gremlin over java or using it over the http api (calculating the parsing time to create the requests)

Comment: Going over the HTTP API would be slightly slower because of the HTTP overhead and data serialization but it might make sense to use a server depending on your application. If you're just getting started with Titan and TinkerPop, I'd recommend learning the Java API first before introducing a server.

Comment: In my special use case access to the database will only be granted over my java code and java socket. It's probably better then, not to switch to a server to eliminate this overhead.

Comment: Make sure you review the Titan chapter on indexing http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html

Comment: Do I have to do anything to connect Titan with gremlin or does:
        GremlinPipeline pipe = new GremlinPipeline();
solve this automatically ?

Comment: There is no GremlinPipeline in Titan 1.0/TinkerPop 3.0. https://github.com/pluradj/titan-tp3-java-example Please read the docs and try writing some code.

Comment: That's what I was searching. Thank you.